# how to iterate thru a json Post with multiple objects and how do I assign it to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json

I am following an API building tutorial, that has served me great thus far. However I've reached a point where the data I want to post to the app & the database is JSON with multiple objects that contain the properties defined below. I believe I need to set it up so that the code iterates thru each object in the JSON POST and assigns each property. However I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

my instict is between the `let {code} = req.body;` and the `let post = new PostBattle`, I should assign the JSON into a variable and then encapsulate the constructor function (let post = new PostBattle) inside this for each.

However how do I grab the JSON and put it into a variable?

`var json = ???;`  is it req.body?

or do i put the variable in front of the `let {code}` ?

so

```
var json = let {summoner_id....etc} = req.body;
```

```
exports.createNewPost = async (req, res, next) => {
    let {summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner
    } = req.body; // using postman this is what allows us to post JSON


    let post = new PostBattle(summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner); // the title & body defined in the previous line taken from the JSON are now deposited here.

    post = await post.save();

    console.log("a post is happening");
    console.log(post);

}
```

example of the JSON (the example below has two objects the app  would need to iterate thru)

```
{
"summoner_id":49,
"summoner_level":1,
"monster_1_id":50,
"monster_1_level":1,
"monster_1_abilities":["Heal"],
"monster_2_id":47,
"monster_2_level":1,
"monster_2_abilities":["Sneak"],
"monster_3_id":51,
"monster_3_level":1,
"monster_3_abilities":["Snipe"],
"monster_4_id":141,
"monster_4_level":1,"monster_4_abilities":["Snipe"],
"monster_5_id":"",
"monster_5_level":"",
"monster_5_abilities":"","monster_6_id":"",
"monster_6_level":"",
"monster_6_abilities":"",
"created_date":"2021-08-03T00:04:03.000Z",
"match_type":"Ranked",
"mana_cap":18,
"ruleset":"Standard",
"inactive":"",
"battle_queue_id":"82428528def07a7db866e94c05c3f3eb197f195f",
"player_rating_initial":157,
"player_rating_final":177,
"winner":"siops"
},
{
"summoner_id":167,
"summoner_level":1,
"monster_1_id":8,"monster_1_level":1,
"monster_1_abilities":["Heal"],
"monster_2_id":4,"monster_2_level":1,
"monster_2_abilities":["Snipe"],
"monster_3_id":158,
"monster_3_level":1,
"monster_3_abilities":["Opportunity"],
"monster_4_id":160,"monster_4_level":1,
"monster_4_abilities":[],"monster_5_id":3,
"monster_5_level":1,
"monster_5_abilities":["Sneak"],
"monster_6_id":"",
"monster_6_level":"",
"monster_6_abilities":"",
"created_date":"2021-08-03T00:01:15.000Z",
"match_type":"Ranked",
"mana_cap":17,
"ruleset":"Standard",
"inactive":"",
"battle_queue_id":"c9d3b611e40d2411a35d44009359b37e0cf2fb06",
"player_rating_initial":230,
"player_rating_final":264,
"winner":"bords"}
```

this seems to work

```
for (var obj in json) {
        console.log(obj + ": " + json[obj]);

        let post = new PostBattle(json[obj].summoner_id, json[obj].summoner_level,
            json[obj].monster_1_id, json[obj].monster_1_level, json[obj].monster_1_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_2_id, json[obj].monster_2_level, json[obj].monster_2_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_3_id, json[obj].monster_3_level, json[obj].monster_3_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_4_id, json[obj].monster_4_level, json[obj].monster_4_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_5_id, json[obj].monster_5_level, json[obj].monster_5_abilities,
            json[obj].monster_6_id, json[obj].monster_6_level, json[obj].monster_6_abilities,
            json[obj].created_date, json[obj].match_type, json[obj].mana_cap, json[obj].ruleset, json[obj].inactive,
            json[obj].battle_queue_id, json[obj].player_rating_initial, json[obj].player_rating_final, json[obj].winner);
        console.log(post);

        //let post = new PostBattle(json);

        post = await post.save();

        console.log("a post is happening");
    }
```

although i'm not sure if it's the best way

The post battle schema looks like this

```
class PostBattle {
    constructor(summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner) {
        this.summoner_id = summoner_id;
        this.summoner_level = summoner_level;
        this.monster_1_id = monster_1_id;
        this.monster_1_level = monster_1_level;
        this.monster_1_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_1_abilities);
        console.log(monster_1_abilities);
        this.monster_2_id = monster_2_id;
        this.monster_2_level = monster_2_level;
        this.monster_2_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_2_abilities);
        this.monster_3_id = monster_3_id;
        this.monster_3_level = monster_3_level;
        this.monster_3_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_3_abilities);
        this.monster_4_id = monster_4_id;
        this.monster_4_level = monster_4_level;
        this.monster_4_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_4_abilities);
        this.monster_5_id = monster_5_id;
        this.monster_5_level = monster_5_level;
        this.monster_5_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_5_abilities);
        this.monster_6_id = monster_6_id;
        this.monster_6_level = monster_6_level;
        this.monster_6_abilities = JSON.stringify(monster_6_abilities);
        this.created_date = created_date;
        this.match_type = match_type;
        this.mana_cap = mana_cap;
        this.ruleset = ruleset;
        this.inactive = inactive;
        this.battle_queue_id = battle_queue_id;
        this.player_rating_initial = player_rating_initial;
        this.player_rating_final = player_rating_final;
        this.winner = winner;

    }
    async save() {
        let sql = `
        INSERT INTO history (summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities,
        monster_2_id, monster_2_level, monster_2_abilities,
        monster_3_id, monster_3_level, monster_3_abilities,
        monster_4_id, monster_4_level, monster_4_abilities,
        monster_5_id, monster_5_level, monster_5_abilities,
        monster_6_id, monster_6_level, monster_6_abilities,
        created_date, match_type, mana_cap, ruleset, inactive,
        battle_queue_id, player_rating_initial, player_rating_final, winner)
        VALUES(
        '${this.summoner_id}',
        '${this.summoner_level}',
        '${this.monster_1_id}',
        '${this.monster_1_level}',
        '${this.monster_1_abilities}',
        '${this.monster_2_id}',
        '${this.monster_2_level}',
        '${this.monster_2_abilities}',
        '${this.monster_3_id}',
        '${this.monster_3_level}',
        '${this.monster_3_abilities}',
        '${this.monster_4_id}',
        '${this.monster_4_level}',
        '${this.monster_4_abilities}',
        '${this.monster_5_id}',
        '${this.monster_5_level}',
        '${this.monster_5_abilities}',
        '${this.monster_6_id}',
        '${this.monster_6_level}',
        '${this.monster_6_abilities}',
        '${this.created_date}',
        '${this.match_type}',
        '${this.mana_cap}',
        '${this.ruleset}',
        '${this.inactive}',
        '${this.battle_queue_id}',
        '${this.player_rating_initial}',
        '${this.player_rating_final}',
        '${this.winner}'
        )
        `;

        const [newPost, _] = await db.execute(sql);

        return newPost;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

```
let json = req.body;
let post = new Post(json);  // Or you can do new Post(req.body) directly, but this is way more insecure
post = await post.save();
```

If you do this, make sure you implement validation to ensure that whatever is passed in the request body meets certain criteria that makes sense for your API.

Comment: so that threw out an error. Let me confirm.

am I replacing 

let {summoner_id, summoner_level,
           } = req.body; 
with 

let json = req.body;

OR do I add 

let json = req.body; 

I tried replacing it

same thing for the below, do I replace the below iwth 

let post = new Post (json); ? 

I replaced them, adn it's throwing out an error 

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, in Json

    let post = new PostBattle(summoner_id, summoner_level,
        monster_1_id, monster_1_level, monster_1_abilities);

Comment: Can you add your `PostBattle` schema/class to your question? That will make it easier to figure out what's causing the problem.

Comment: actually I figured it out! ugh enter is so annoying on this - i posted my solution, as well as the post battle schema as per your request. would love to get further feedback on it